# cocoapods code signing issue while using with Jenkins

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, jenkins, cocoapods

I have created a job for Xcode project which has dependencies of cocoapods.
I am able to get the code from cocoa pods using Execute shell script.
I have set the Scheme file as my main project file .    *Only needed if you want to compile for a specific schema instead of a target.*
But the problem is instead of building only main project Jenkins is trying to build Pod projects also and I am getting the code signing error.

How to restrict the pod projects from building.

Comment: instead of giving **-workspace workspacename.xcworkspace** in *xcodebuild* you could try **-project ProjName.xcodeproj** right ! or you can simply go to the code settings and give don't code sign in build settings